# Density of the irrationals using the density of the rationals

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

I have just proved the density of the rationals via the classic Archimedean Property method. I now need to prove the density of the irrationals.

I thought of a method which uses the density of the rationals to do this but I am not sure if it is valid.

Proof:

From the density of the rationals I have that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R},$$ \exists z \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $x<z<y$

Since $x$ and $y$ can be any real value I set them to be $x + \sqrt2$ and $y + \sqrt2$. Then using the density of the rationals I can do the following $x + \sqrt2 < z < y +\sqrt2 \implies x<z-\sqrt2<y$ which yields an irrational number between $x$ and $y$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: What you seem to be saying is that you can choose a rational greater than $x+\sqrt{2}$ and less than $y+\sqrt{2}$, which is true if $x<y$ though you might state this requirement, and by subtracting the irrational $\sqrt{2}$ from everything this implies there is an irrational between $x$ and $y$, and that is a good proof.  I would not say you set $x$ to be $x+\sqrt{2}$, as that looks confusing, but it can be reworded to be clearer.

Comment: @Henry Ah I see cheers :)